# Seeing contents of war file without extracting

Tags: tomcat, jar, war

I created a simple web application and deployed in Tomcat using the admin console of Tomcat. Now, this war files gets stored in tomcat location under webapps directory.

Is there a way to see the contents of this war without extracting? I know we can see the contents of war file by extracting  using jar -xvf ; however is there any tool/mechanism by which to see the contents of war files without extracting it?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `t` option to the command line `jar` program will list the contents of a jar (or war) file, e.g.:

```
$ jar tf the-file.war
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs; is there any GUI tool in which we can "open" the war file just to see the contents?

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but you can use 7-zip or other similar software to view the contents of the .war

With 7-zip:
Right click on file.war -> Open archive

Answer (score 2):

Verbose version of matts answer

You can use `jar` command.

It is a general-purpose archiving and compression tool.

- The `t` option or `--list`
  Lists the table of contents for the archive.
- The `f` option or `-f FILE` or `--file=FILE`
  Specifies the archive file name.

so the complete command in this case is

```
jar tf the-file.war
```

More options and details can be found from docs here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jar.html